# Google App engine for mobile clients

Tags: google-app-engine, mobile

Can I use GAE(Google App Engine) for developing a server for mobile clients? Mobile clients will send data to server every 10 seconds.
I am planning to develop the prototype using GAE and then depending on the results, will decide where to locate the prod server.
And are there any best practices to follow in developing code so that it will have very minimal dependancy with GAE (Can easily port to another environment with minimal code change when required)

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse you can, GAE provides a good way to create a great backend for a mobile app.
about dependencies, you can use a project like [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), it creates an interface between your code and the API of GAE.